# Updating ngModel with value returned from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Being unhappy with the way Angular does form validation, I decided to implement my own, and have run into an issue that has honestly left me stumped.

My setup is as follows:

1. A directive is used to instantiate a new form.
2. Its controller accesses the relevant form schema, which is then used to generate fields in the view via `ng-repeat`.
3. These input & textarea fields are then bound to the controller via `ng-model`.
4. On field change or form submit, the controller sends the form data to a validation service which returns an error if applicable, itself then bound to the DOM.

I've run into an issue trying to implement a sanitation step before the validation in part 4. This sanitation step should in theory update the controller data with the return value from a service method, updating the DOM binding and allowing the validation step to use the updated value. Although the controller value itself is being updated, this change is not being reflected in the DOM.

The relevant code is as follows:

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="(field, value) in form.schema">
  <!-- ... -->
  <textarea ng-model="form.data[field]" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="form.changed(field)"></textarea>
  <div class="message">{{ form.errors[field] }}</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
// Controller submit method
ctrl.submit = function () {

  var err;

  for (var field in ctrl.schema) {
    ctrl.data[field] = validationService.sanitizeField(ctrl.data[field], ctrl.schema[field]);
    ctrl.errors[field] = validationService.validateField(ctrl.data[field], ctrl.schema[field]);
    if (ctrl.errors[field] !== undefined) {
      err = true;
    }
  }

  if (err) {
    return;
  }

  // Proceed ...
```

Service:

```
// Public field sanitation method
var sanitizeField = function (value, schema) {
  try {
    // Try sanitation
  }
  catch (e) {
    // Error
  }
  return value;
}
```

Logging the new `ctrl.data[field]` value in the controller after sanitation yields the correct result. This result is also being correctly passed to the subsequent `validateField` method. However, the new data value isn't being updated in the DOM.

At first, I figured it might be an issue with the scope not being applied, or an issue with promises. Updating the service & controller accordingly didn't solve the issue. I've also tried wrapping the sanitation return value in an object, to no avail.

Strangely enough, changing the return value in the service from the `value` variable to a primitive, e.g. `'test'`, updates the DOM on return.

Likewise, errors returned from the service validation method (also strings rather than a variable) are updated in the DOM accordingly.

Despite a decent amount of searching, I haven't been able to find anything concrete on the topic. Any insights would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

Unbeknownst to me, Angular features an `ngTrim` directive which is automatically bound to input fields and is by default set to `true` [[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)].

With this directive, data is automatically trimmed before being picked up by the controller on form submission - the trimming being performed by my sanitation service therefore wasn't changing the data, which in turn wouldn't be reflected in the DOM as Angular wasn't picking up any changes.

This behaviour can be mitigated by setting `ng-trim="false"` on relevant fields in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the follwoing;

```
  for (var field in ctrl.schema) {
    ctrl.data[field] = angular.copy(validationService.sanitizeField(ctrl.data[field], ctrl.schema[field]));
    ctrl.errors[field] = angular.copy(validationService.validateField(ctrl.data[field], ctrl.schema[field]));
    if (ctrl.errors[field] !== undefined) {
      err = true;
    }
  }
```

Angular is tricky when it comes to updating objects/arrays with nested properties. You can either use `$scope.$watchCollection` to make sure that the object/array has updated, or you can use `angular.copy()`, which will make sure that DOM updates.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work! Running the sanitizeField result through `angular.copy()` doesn't change anything, and specifying `ctrl.data[field]` as the optional destination parameter yields an `Can't copy! Source and destination are identical` error :(